# How to get the Ln (0) from generating functions for Laguerre polynomials?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, generating-functions

The problem given was that I had to evaluate $L_n(0)$ given the generating function for Laguerre polynomials is:

$g(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} L_n(x) t^n = \frac {e^{xt/(1-t)}}{1-t}$

I tried substituting x as zero but I'm not sure it's correct because it seems too easy. I ended up with:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} L_n(0) t^n = \frac {e^{xt/(1-t)}}{1-t}= \frac {e^0}{1-t} =\frac {1}{1-t}$

Am I going the right path? If yes, where can I go from here? If no, what should I have done? Thank you in advance to anyone who would be able to help me understand this better!

Comment: That's fine ... now geometrically expand $1/(1-t)=1+t+t^2+\cdots $ and conclude $L_n(0)=1$ for all $n$ ... really as easy as that.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Alright, thank you!